# Find the volume of the Region (Triple Integral with Cylindrical Coordinates)

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, volume, multiple-integral, cylindrical-coordinates

Question: Find the volume of the region that is contained by the cylinder $x^2+y^2=81$, bounded above by $z=x$ and below by the $xy$-plane.

I have tried the integral $\int_{0}^{2pi}\int_{0}^{9}\int_{0}^{rcos\theta}r^3dzdrd\theta$ and got $0$, same when $0\leq\theta\leq\pi$. Then I tried $\int_{0}^{pi/2}\int_{0}^{9}\int_{0}^{rcos\theta}r^3dzdrd\theta$ and got 11809.8. Which is also wrong.

Comment: why is there $r^3$? shouldnt there just be an r in the change of coordinates , im assuming your integrating with the caratheristic function.

Answer (score 2):

If you are bounded *below* by the $xy$ plane and bounded *above* by the $z=x$ plane, then $z\geqslant0$ and $z\leqslant x$. So, $x\geqslant 0$ and so, since $x=\rho\cos\theta$, $\theta\in\left[-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2\right]$. So, you consider the integral$$\int_{-\frac\pi2}^{\frac\pi2}\int_0^9\int_0^{\rho\cos\theta}\rho\,\mathrm dz\,\mathrm d\rho\,\mathrm d\theta.$$You should get $486$.